# Setting TTL(expireAfterSeconds) on created_timestamp object inside my array

Tags: python, mongodb, ttl, pymongo-3.x

So I have a mongo collection called 'abcd', inside my collection I am creating indexes called 'token'. I understand that TTL needs to be tied to a ISO datetime object in mongo as an index, or as part of an array.

I was unsuccessful at getting the token to expire when adding an index to my 'token'. So I am adding a `created_timestamp` ISO date object into my "data" array of my token index.

My question is, how can I use my `expireAfterSeconds=10` attribute to the object of created_timestamp of my data array. My goal is to get the entire token index to delete after 10 seconds. Here is a json of what my 'token' document looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7dec4189284441fe9aa1fc"),
"token" : "RfAQ3W",
"data" : "{\"token\": {\"user_id\": 308, \"exp\": 151821111, \"team_code\": 1022, \"created_timestamp\": \"2018-02-09T18:45:24.823785\}}"
```

}

I want to be able to expire my token after 10 seconds from the `created_timestamp` which is the ISO date of when the token gets generated to mongodb

I am using: 
Pymongo 3.4
Mongoengine 0.13
Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new field 'created_at' with Date() value and make it TTL index instead of putting this in an array?

After all this whole document is going to delete after 10 sec.

Comment: Is it possible for me to set an `expireAfterSeconds` attribute to a `collection.insert()` function?

Comment: According to mongo docs, i can only use that ttl feature when using `create_index()`. issue with that is my application does not use `create_index` but rather insert

Comment: @locodev123 You just have to create index once. Don't bother about it after that. You can insert then normally

Comment: when i create my index like so: 
`c.create_index('token', expireAfterSeconds=20)`
My tokens that i am generating are not getting deleted from database after 20 seconds..

Comment: Use MongoDb Compass for easy GUI interaction with your database. That is very useful

Comment: c is the collection object, i have this inside a conditional check, if 
`c = self.db.create_collection(self.collection_name)` if collection does not exists, else: `c.create_index('token', expireAfterSeconds=20)`